# Unable to access grafana from the browser due to failed loading of static files

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, grafana

I want to access grafana from my browser and make it available publicly. However, I am receiving the following error:

```
If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files 

1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.

2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath

3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build

4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help
```

I tried going through some issues and added the domain name in the `grafana`'s settings. My NGINX is perfect and as per the documentation. In fact, everything was working well. The problem is in the anonymous session *i.e.* if I try to load this in no-user mode, it doesn't load. In the logged-in mode, it loads but without all the dashboards that I had created.

My NGINX conf is as follows:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=grafana_cache:10m max_size=20g
                 inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

server {

        server_name foo.bar www.foo.bar;

        location / {
                proxy_cache grafana_cache;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.bar/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.bar/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = www.foo.bar) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = foo.bar) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name foo.bar www.foo.bar;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

I expect the `grafana` dashboard to be working with and without the user logging in.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Comment below didn't apply to me either. Started happening possibly only on certain browsers.

Comment: Yeah, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57371689/10834788.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `hash_bucket_size` set to 64 in my `nginx.conf` and got it working.